# Horizontal scroll view Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UIscrollView to create a horizontal scrollable box.
Using API data to display in scroll view, so according to string length I am setting content Size of the UIscrollView.

When the text is longer than the actual box size I am terminating the text using dots (Ellipses) and when user starts scrolling, I am displaying complete string.

Following is the code to create horizontal scrollable box:

```
let VarStrValue = rowArray[4] as! String

let stringCount  = (VarStrValue).characters.count
let lengthOfString = CGFloat(stringCount)*7


let VarView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
let Varframe = CGRect(x:545, y:yTopMargin, width:455, height:45)
VarView.frame=Varframe            

VarView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(lengthOfString, 0)
VarView.backgroundColor=UIColor(red:220/255, green: 221/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0)
VarView.delegate = self            


let InfoVarValuelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 0, 455, 40))
InfoVarValuelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
InfoVarValuelabel.text = VarStrValue
InfoVarValuelabel.textColor = UIColor(red:82/255, green:87/255, blue:95/255, alpha:1.0)
InfoVarValuelabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 11.0)
InfoVarValuelabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
VarView.addSubview(InfoVarValuelabel)

self.MemValueVu.addSubview(VarView)



func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let subviews = scrollView.subviews

    for v in subviews {
        if v is UILabel {
            let VarLabel = v as! UILabel
            let VarString = VarLabel.text

            let stringCount  = (VarString)!.characters.count
            let lengthOfString = CGFloat(stringCount)


            print("scrollView.contentOffset.x \(scrollView.contentOffset.x)")
            if(scrollView.contentOffset.x > (lengthOfString/7))
            {
                VarLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 5000, 40)
                VarLabel.text = VarString
                VarLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail

            }
            else{
                VarLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, 455, 40)
                VarLabel.text = VarString
                VarLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But in doing so I am having issues:
1) Extra scroll is getting added to the string even if the string is not so long.

2)In some cases, complete string is not getting displayed or there is a slight delay in display of complete string, even though I have scrolled half of the content.It should display the complete string as soon as user starts scrolling.

Can you suggest how to fix this?

Comment: You can do one thing. Finding height of label and added that height into scrollview height

Comment: @Jecky I need to scroll only in horizontal direction, but vertically content size needs to be remain zero beacuse I do not need vertical scrolls, so how adding height to scrollview will solve my problem?

Comment: You want to do like this ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/zedbmuqsmynx5zn/Untitled.mov?dl=0

Comment: No, I have a text area where I have long text. If I swipe it, it needs to replace ellipsis to actual text.

Comment: I dont understand your issue really

Comment: Why shouldn't you use auto layout ??